# Run sh script with java but it fails without showing the error

Tags: java, sh

I am trying to loop into files, and run the script sh in each file using JAVA.

```
for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {           
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start "
                             +file.getAbsolutePath()+"\\creationNoPersisWF12.sh");
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1800);}}
```

The window of the script opens and get closed immediately.
However, when I try the execute the scripts sh from outside, they execute successfully.

I need some help please.

Comment: are you positive there isn't a stack trace?
are you positive that the name of the sh file is correct?

Comment: yes i'm 100% positive. In fact, it starts the script, but get closed in like 5 seconds. I want to have the stack trace in order to understand the problem but no success.

Comment: catch and Write the stacktrace to a file.

Comment: I tried by using 'Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start "
+file.getAbsolutePath()+"\\creationNoPersisWF12.sh">>path/logerror.txt);  I get the text file but it's empty

Comment: Since when `cmd.exe` is able to run shell scripts?

Comment: There is another way to execute it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start "
                             +file.getAbsolutePath()+"\\creationNoPersisWF12.sh");
    if(process.exitValue()!=0){
        throw new RuntimeException(new String(process.getErrorStream().readAllBytes()));
    }
```

you have to check the exit value and read the error stream for the errors since its a process on its own, it won't throw any error on its own after invoking the process you have to check if it ran successfully with exitvalue 0 or not.

Comment: The project won't compile : The method readAllBytes() is undefined for the type InputStream

Comment: @LSoft readAllBytes is available since Java 9, so it won't be available if you are on java 8 or lower.

Comment: @LSoft https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-string-in-java

Comment: I tried this  int exitVal =process.waitFor();            
System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);  The exit value is 1